Base Page Scroll must be retained when Dialog is opened
v-dialog of Vuetify when opens the base page scroll gets reset to top how to prevent the scroll of base page resetting so that when dialog is open the base page scroll is maintained.
Example:
There is a page built with Vue Framework and Vuetify is used.
I scroll down the home page and at the end there is a link.
When i click on the link the v-model opens , but the issue is the v-dialog when opens take the base page scroll to top.
Expected behavior must be the scroll position of base page must be same before and after the dialog is open
Tried with setting style and few Vuetify props.
Main component:
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Table Component -->
    <table>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
        <td>
          <a @click="openModal($event, item)">Open Modal</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <!-- Modal Component -->
    <ModalComponent v-if="showModal" :position="modalPosition" @close="closeModal">
      <!-- Modal Content -->
    </ModalComponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import ModalComponent from './ModalComponent.vue';

const items = [ /* Your table data */ ];
const showModal = ref(false);
const modalPosition = ref({ top: '0px', left: '0px' });

const openModal = (event, item) => {
  showModal.value = true;
  const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  // Calculate the position relative to the viewport
  const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  const scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;

  // Position the modal near the clicked element
  modalPosition.value = {
    top: `${rect.top + scrollTop}px`,
    left: `${rect.left + scrollLeft}px`,
  };
};

const closeModal = () => {
  showModal.value = false;
};
</script>

Modal component:
<template>
  <div class="modal" :style="{ top: position.top, left: position.left }">
    <button @click="$emit('close')">Close</button>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- Modal Content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  position: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
});
</script>


Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Do not just talk about your code - but show relevant parts of it. Right now, can't tell if this is a problem with the dialog itself, or just how you are triggering it.

Not easy to tell without knowing what you tried so far. "Tried with setting style and few vuetify props.", is a bit vague. Give a try to this one?

Sure I have tried with approach like.
when I tried opening the modal and storing value in ref
modalPosition.value = { top: window.pageXOffset }
and passing this prop to modal and binding it with styles
<v-dialog :style="{ top: position.top }"

@kissu I have used scrollable prop it will allow the scrolling in background too and user and scroll inside modal too.
But my question is when I open my dialog the base page scroll position is lost

Check your code formatting

Why not just change the positioning to "fixed"? See MDN docs: Fixed positioning: "This can be used to create a "floating" element that stays in the same position regardless of scrolling."

@Peter The issue is not of position fixed suppose you scroll and reach to the bottom of webpage and then there is link in bottom when you click the Modal appears but the modal open in background and page scroll is moved to beginning.
I want when I open the modal the scroll part is not removed.

Oh I noticed you open your modals with an a tag. Because the a tag has no href I assume the browser brings you to the top of the page. Don't use an a tag, use a button like with the close button you have. Alternatively call event.preventDefault();.

For me when I open the modal I capture the scroll position and when modal closes, scroll back to the position saved.
In Vue.js 3:
const scrollPosition = ref(null);
// inside pop function where we are setting isModalVisible = true
scrollPosition.value = window.scrollY;
// inside closeModal function setting isModalVisible = false
nextTick(() => {
  window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition.value);
});

